# Using two mosfet in diode connected structure

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, differential-amplifier

I read that the structure in green are diode connected. I am only familiar with the single device version of diode connected MOSFET. Can you tell me what's the advantage doing it using two devices as shown? Thank you. I'm self learning please bear with me.

[image]

Comment: Your circuit is incorrect.

Comment: How is that wrong? My professor drew that

Comment: Well, you better ask him if you think he knows more about electronics than me.